# Error in disable mouse click in div using jquery

Tags: jquery

I wanna to disable the mouse clicking in some div.For this I have used the die function it is not working. Please let me know how can I do it? Is it possible in jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very simple. Use this code:

```
$("#DIV_ID").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   e.stopPropagation()
});
```

Comment: There probably is no default action performed by the div .. you may want to use `stopImmediatePropagation` instead or even unbind whatever event is bound to it.

Comment: @ExplosionPills I am not sure about `stopImmediatePropagation`. Can you explain difference b/w `stopImmediatePropagation` and `stopPropagation`?

Comment: It prevents the calling of other events bound to the same element.  `stopPropagation` only stops the calling of events bound to ancestors.

Answer (score 1):

use [stopImmediatePropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/)...

> Keeps the rest of the handlers from being executed and prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree.

try this

```
$("#yourDivId").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
```